# Trigonometric Identities To Prove

Tags: trigonometry

1. $\tan\theta+\cot\theta=\dfrac{2}{\sin2\theta}$

Left Side:
$$\begin{align*}
 \tan\theta+\cot\theta={\sin\theta\over\cos\theta}+{\cos\theta\over\sin\theta}={\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\over\cos\theta\sin\theta}
= \dfrac{1}{1\sin\theta\cos\theta}
\end{align*}$$
Right Side:
$$\begin{align*}
 \dfrac{2}{\sin2\theta}=\dfrac{2}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}=\dfrac{1}{1\cos\theta\sin\theta}
\end{align*}$$

I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: Your first line under "left side" has a pretty substantial error in adding fractions. You need to find a common denominator.

Comment: That's **not** how you add fractions! Is $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}$ equal to $\frac{1+1}{3+5}$?

Comment: @TheChaz Didn't notice that. Thank you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I told you my brain is working too fast! I've been doing this stuff for hours!

Comment: @Austin: Sorry, but I don't see how that error comes from "brain working to fast". If anything, it comes from "brain working too slow"...

Comment: Because I'm thinking faster than I type so I skip over fundamental principals and just decided to add unlike denominators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan(\theta) + \cot(\theta) = {\sin(\theta)\over \cos(\theta)} + {\cos(\theta)\over \sin(\theta)} = {\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) \over\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}
= {1\over\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}.$$
Now avail yourself of the fact that $$\sin(2\theta) = 2\cos(
\theta)\sin(\theta).$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll just put together what you wrote...
$$\begin{align*}
 \tan\theta+\cot\theta=\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}+\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=\dfrac{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta}{\cos\theta \cdot\sin\theta}  = \dfrac{1}{\cos \theta \cdot \sin \theta}
\end{align*}$$

Where the penultimate inequality is what you *should have written*.

Can you take it from here?